# What does 2/(e^(-x)+1) mean?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm just a little bit confused about having $e^{-x}$ in the denominator. Does that mean that e is positive? I came across one of these problems while solving an integral. What I did was, I let my $u = e^{-x} + 1$, therefore $du = -\frac{1}{e^x}dx$. My first thought was to factor by doing $(2 + e^x - e^x)/(e^{-x}+1)$ but that negative in the denominator is not letting me solve the problem? The answer is, by the way, $2\ln(1+e^x)+c$. Which made me wonder about how did the book get u to be $1 + e^x$, meaning having a positive $e^x$. Any help in explaining this would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $e$ is a constant, known as Euler or Napier's constant, $$ e = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 2.718281828459\ldots$$

Comment: And the exponential $e^x$ fulfills $$ e^x = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!} $$ for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know e is a constant. I want to know is what does having 2/(e^(-x)+1) means, more specifically having the e^(-x) in the denominator.

Comment: If you know what $e^x$ means, you also know what $e^{-x}$ means, namely $$ e^{-x} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: Then $\frac{A}{B+C}$ means precisely $\frac{A}{B+C}$.

Comment: What do you mean what does it mean?  $\frac 1{e^{-x} + 1}$ means $\frac 1{(\frac 1e)^x + 1}$.  What else would it mean?  Just like $\frac 1{2^{-1} + 1} = \frac 1{\frac 12 + 1}$.  You can put whatever you darn well please (except 0) in the denominator.  And you can make your expression as straightforward or convoluted as you like.

Comment: "Does that mean that e is positive?"  e is a constant and can't ever *not* be positive no matter what you do to it.  As for ${-x}$ that could be positive or negative or zero.

Comment: If $u = e^{-1} + 1$ then $du = 0$.

Comment: @fleablood Finally someone that was able to understand what I was asking! you reminded me about how simple a problem can be, all it takes is going back to the basic. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put $u=1+e^{-x} $ then you write

$$\int \frac {2e^{-x}dx}{e^{-x}(e^{-x}+1)} $$

$$=2\int  \frac {-du}{u (u-1)} $$
$$=2\int (\frac {du}{u}-\frac {du}{u-1}) $$
$$=2\ln (|\frac {u}{u-1}|) $$
$$=2\ln (e^x+1)+C $$

Comment: If my u = e^x then it would not give me the correct result. According to the answer my u is 1+e^x because is a ln function meaning the my u has to be the denominator.

Comment: @JulioRosario Look now, i did what you said.